# Invalid entity type provided in the request on composite/tree/customObject

Tags: integration, composite, allornone, sobject-tree

I'm trying to receive a POST call with multiple records of a custom object. I don't know if that's the best choice but i'm using **/services/data/v47.0/composite/tree/CSVEnergyLead__c/**

When i try to do a post from workbench i'm always receiving same **errors**:

```
400 Bad request


{
  "hasErrors" : true,
  "results" : [ {
    "referenceId" : "Ref1",
    "errors" : [ {
      "statusCode" : "INVALID_INPUT",
      "message" : "Invalid entity type provided in the request.",
      "fields" : [ ]
    } ]
  }, {
    "referenceId" : "Ref2",
    "errors" : [ {
      "statusCode" : "INVALID_INPUT",
      "message" : "Invalid entity type provided in the request.",
      "fields" : [ ]
    } ]
  }, {
    "referenceId" : "Ref3",
    "errors" : [ {
      "statusCode" : "INVALID_INPUT",
      "message" : "Invalid entity type provided in the request.",
      "fields" : [ ]
    } ]
  }, {
    "referenceId" : "Ref4",
    "errors" : [ {
      "statusCode" : "INVALID_INPUT",
      "message" : "Invalid entity type provided in the request.",
      "fields" : [ ]
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

The **POST JSON** is defined as follows:

```
{
    "records": [{
        "attributes": {
            "type": "CSVEnergyLead__c ",
            "referenceId": "Ref1"
        },
        "CallDuration__c": null,
        "CallId__c": null,
        "ClosingDate__c": "2018-11-19",
        "CUPS1__c": "ES0021000007700837DC1F",
        "CUPS2__c": "ES0222120070014189CT",
        "ErrorLog__c": "Error en inserción por causas desconcidas",
        "Lead__c": "a3358000001iLVaAAM",
        "Lead_Fotofactura_Id__c": "a3358000001hTQmAAM",
        "LegibleBill__c": false,
        "Phone__c": null,
        "ProcessId__c": "7075800006sGNHpAAO",
        "ProcessStatus__c": "Cargado",
        "RejectionReason__c": "13_AGENDADO",
        "RPSClosing__c": false,
        "SellingAgency__c": "0015800001JLofOAAT",
        "SellingAgent__c": null,
        "SellingTime__c": "9:00:00.000Z",
        "Stage__c": "En gestión",
        "SupplierE__c": "IBERDROLA",
        "SupplierG__c": "IBERDROLA"
    }, {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "CSVEnergyLead__c ",
            "referenceId": "Ref2"
        },
        "CallDuration__c": null,
        "CallId__c": null,
        "ClosingDate__c": "2018-11-19",
        "CUPS1__c": "ES0021000007700837DC1F",
        "CUPS2__c": "ES0222120070014189CT",
        "ErrorLog__c": "",
        "Lead__c": "a334I000001wOqJQAU",
        "Lead_Fotofactura_Id__c": "a3358000001hTQmAAM",
        "LegibleBill__c": false,
        "Phone__c": null,
        "ProcessId__c": "7075800006sGNHpAAO",
        "ProcessStatus__c": "Cargado",
        "RejectionReason__c": "13_AGENDADO",
        "RPSClosing__c": false,
        "SellingAgency__c": "0015800001JLofOAAT",
        "SellingAgent__c": null,
        "SellingTime__c": "9:00:00.000Z",
        "Stage__c": "En gestión",
        "SupplierE__c": "IBERDROLA",
        "SupplierG__c": "IBERDROLA"
    }, {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "CSVEnergyLead__c ",
            "referenceId": "Ref3"
        },
        "CallDuration__c": null,
        "CallId__c": null,
        "ClosingDate__c": "2018-11-19",
        "CUPS1__c": "ES0021000007700837DC1F",
        "CUPS2__c": "ES0222120070014189CT",
        "ErrorLog__c": "",
        "Lead__c": "a3358000001hToUAAU",
        "Lead_Fotofactura_Id__c": "a3358000001hTQmAAM",
        "LegibleBill__c": false,
        "Phone__c": null,
        "ProcessId__c": "7075800006sGNHpAAO",
        "ProcessStatus__c": "Cargado",
        "RejectionReason__c": "13_AGENDADO",
        "RPSClosing__c": false,
        "SellingAgency__c": "0015800001JLofOAAT",
        "SellingAgent__c": null,
        "SellingTime__c": "9:00:00.000Z",
        "Stage__c": "En gestión",
        "SupplierE__c": "IBERDROLA",
        "SupplierG__c": "IBERDROLA"
    }, {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "CSVEnergyLead__c ",
            "referenceId": "Ref4"
        },
        "CallDuration__c": null,
        "CallId__c": null,
        "ClosingDate__c": "2018-11-19",
        "CUPS1__c": "ES0021000007700837DC1F",
        "CUPS2__c": "ES0222120070014189CT",
        "ErrorLog__c": "",
        "Lead__c": "a3358000001hTQmAAM",
        "Lead_Fotofactura_Id__c": "a3358000001hTQmAAM",
        "LegibleBill__c": false,
        "Phone__c": null,
        "ProcessId__c": "7075800006sGNHpAAO",
        "ProcessStatus__c": "Cargado",
        "RejectionReason__c": "13_AGENDADO",
        "RPSClosing__c": false,
        "SellingAgency__c": "0015800001JLofOAAT",
        "SellingAgent__c": null,
        "SellingTime__c": "9:00:00.000Z",
        "Stage__c": "En gestión",
        "SupplierE__c": "IBERDROLA",
        "SupplierG__c": "IBERDROLA"
    }]
}
```

So the question is, i'm getting that error because of the defined JSON, because of any value that is not expected (example boolean as a string) or there is simply a better way to do that?

The goal is that the process emulates the allOrNone = false. I'm not using a custom web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. The problem was the space in "type": "CSVEnergyLead__c ". Thanks anyway.